# LLVM: how to assign an array element?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm struggling to figure out how to assign an array element using the LLVM c++ API.
consider this C code:

```c
int main()
{
    int aa[68];
    aa[56] = 7;

    return 0;
}
```

using

```bash
clang -S -emit-llvm main.c
```

I get the following IR (attributes and other things are skipped for simplicity):

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca [68 x i32], align 16
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds [68 x i32], [68 x i32]* %2, i64 0, i64 56
  store i32 7, i32* %3, align 16
  ret i32 0
}
```

I already know how to create an inbounds GEP, but when storing a value (7) to the array the type is a pointer to i32.

my language is very similar to C, that's why I'm using C as an example (so far it's just C but with a different syntax).
generated IR for my language is:

```
define i32 @main() {
  %0 = alloca [2 x i32], align 4
  %1 = getelementptr [2 x i32], [2 x i32]* %0, i32 1
  store i32 1, [2 x i32]* %1, align 4
  ret i32 0
}
```

how can I possibly turn [2 x i32]* into i32* when creating a store?
this is how I create the store:

```cpp
llvm::AllocaInst *stored = symbol_table[arr_name];
llvm::Value *result = ir_builder->CreateGEP(stored->getAllocatedType(), stored, idx_vals); 
// idx_vals contains the index

ir_builder->CreateStore(val, result); // here val is a value stored in a symbol table
                                      // and it's type is llvm::Value *
```

Comment: To supplement my answer, here's an answer to a related question you didn't ask: how could you store a `[2 x i32]` through a `[2 x i32]*` in a single store instruction. Build a `[2 x i32]` with `%A = insertvalue [2 x i32] undef, i32 7, 0`  `%B = insertvalue [2 x i32] %A, i32 8, 1`. You can call `thing->dump()` on any value or type to see what it is (for values it includes the type). You should be able to see that your `%1` was a `[2 x i32]*` and not an `i32*`, also that the `%B` in my example is a `[2 x i32]` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I possibly turn [2 x i32]* into i32* when creating a store?

This is exactly what the "get element pointer" instruction does. You have a pointer to an object like a struct or an array, and you want a pointer to one element.

> ```
> %1 = getelementptr [2 x i32], [2 x i32]* %0, i32 1
> ```

This isn't quite what you want. Picture a C string in memory, you don't have a `[*number* x i8]*` you just have an `i8*`. If you had a pointer to `[*number* x i8]*` you'd be stepping into that array and getting a pointer to one of its elements, but with a C string you have a pointer to a single `i8` element and you step over it, advancing your pointer by *sizeof* the pointee.

What your `%1` is doing is stepping over one whole `[2 x i32]` and pointing to another full `[2 x i32]` after it. You don't want to step over at all, so your first index should be `i32 0`. Then you want to step into it and select the second `i32` in your `2 x i32`? Use `i32 1` as your second index.

```
%1 = getelementptr [2 x i32], [2 x i32]* %0, i32, 0, i32 1
```

produces an `i32*`.

See the LLVM GEP FAQ: https://www.llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html